# How to handle browser trusted certificate messages thru selinium

Tags: selenium

For few of the URL's in our company we are getting "Your connection is not private" message in chrome and "There is a problem with this website’s security certificate." in IE. Need to handle this to execute my script. I was not getting these mesages on FF browser. I was unable to capture properties of these links using FireBug Addon. Please help.

[Scressnhot of IE message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XxZM.jpg)
[ScreenShot of Chrome message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys5Cu.jpg)

Comment: What language are you tests written in?

Comment: Selinium with Java

Comment: can anyone please help on this issue???